# .editorconfig file does not fix file ending issues in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, editorconfig

I'm doing a project with a few other people and we have defined a .editorconfig file

```
# http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = crlf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

Even so I keep getting the message that line endings are not consistent. Why is this happening? Why isn't the .editorconfig file fixing the issue? Shouldn't that file make people automatically save files in the correct way?